# jquery AJAX - PHP returns json_encode values but not able to decode in javascript

Tags: jquery

[image]

Php returns the json_encode as object. Please refer the above image. 
Can you please help me in getting the data

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `console.log(customer[0], customer[0].address1);`

Comment: ^^ That coupled with a few for loops should be able to do just about anything. Further info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Show your code, show any error output

Comment: No error. Am trying to parse the output which comes as object. which is like {"customer":[{"id":1,"name":"test"},{"id":3,"name":"firstname"}]}

Comment: That looks like a pure JSON string to me. You can parse it in PHP using the examples from the link I posted above or if you really want to parse it using Javascript try this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp